# How do I connect installed module to python shell?

Tags: python, pip, numpy

I have downloaded 'numpy' by using

```
pip install numpy
```

and it says that my installation is successful. I have also installed python 3.7.3 on Windows, but everytime I try to import numpy on the python shell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How do I 'connect' my already installed numpy to the actual python shell?

Comment: " I have also installed python 3.7.3 on Windows" what do you meane by that? and do consider the fact we ONLY support the official versions of operating system Ubuntu on AskUBUNTU. I don't see WSL mentioned in your question, Not the usage of Ubuntu. You are asking this using Windows OS?

Comment: I'm sorry as I hadn't realized that this question would be invalid in this circumstance. I am thankful for the answers that I have received and they all seem to work. I would delete the question if I could.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` most likely belongs to Python 2. For Python 3, it would normally need to be `pip3`.

You should usually avoid calling these executables directly though, because it is not well defined which instance of Python they belong to if you have more than one version installed.

The recommended alternative is to call it as module with the exact interpreter you want:

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy is connected automatically to the Python shell with `import numpy as np` if you install numpy from the default Ubuntu repositories. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```